# Does changing the frequency of a wave cause a change of the phase of the same wave?

Tags: signal-analysis

I know that the phase is the delay between two different waves . But if we change the frequency of two waves by a different value does it cause a varying in the phase between them let say that two waves start from the same point.and if I apply that in the single wave and change the frequency does that related to the phase !
My main question related to the Fm and Pm modulation

Comment: I guess it depends on how you change the frequency. I mean, I can take $e^{j(2\pi f_0 t + \phi_0)}$ and multiply it by $e^{j2\pi f_1 t}$ to obtain $e^{j(2\pi (f_0+f_1) t + \phi_0)}$ and I changed the frequency without changing the phase. Can you try to clarify what you're actually trying to ask?

Comment: Just by increase or decrease the number of cycles per second in the same wave or in the two waves. Let say I generate a carrier wave at 10khz then changes it to 100 khz does that causes changing in the phase of the same wave and on the other side I asked about two waves starts from the same point at the same phase but with different frequency what will happen to the phase between them!?

Comment: It isn’t clear what your asking. What do you mean by same wave. A wave has a wavelength that is a function of temporal frequency and propagation  speed. Hygens principle relates to wave fronts and there is also Fermat’s principle of least time.  To change the frequency of a wave where it is the same wave is called Doppler and that doesn’t make much sense, given your question

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your two sinusoids are at the same phase, $\phi_0$, at $t=0$ and you change the frequency of one of them at exactly that time.

The phases as functions of time, for $t \ge 0$, for those sinusoids at the two different frequencies are

$$\phi_1(t) = 2\pi f_1 t + \phi_0$$
$$\phi_2(t) = 2\pi f_2 t + \phi_0$$

And the difference between those phases is

$$\psi(t) = \phi_1(t)-\phi_2(t) = 2\pi(f_1-f_2)t$$

So the phase difference between them is a function of time and the difference between the two frequencies.